# What is claimed here about a vulnerability in the target of a "really common shell"?

Tags: shellcode, bash

in https://twitter.com/nnwakelam/status/1363761612423786496, its tweeted:

> fucking yikes.. ran every bitcoin exchange for a really common shell and found....

```
Uname: Linux cloudimage 4.4.0-166-generic #195-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 09:36:25 UTC 2019 i686
User: 33 [ www-data ] Group: 33 [ www.data ]
7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16 Safe Mode: OFF
```

Some of that might be anonymized...?

what is the vulnerability here? What "really common shell" might he/she be talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're claiming that they found a webshell installed on a bitcoin exchange site.  So the vulnerability is that someone has already compromised the exchange's server and left the webshell sitting ready to take commands from anybody... and that as a "really common shell", lots of people would know how to find it and use it.

Not enough information to tell which common shell it is, however.

Comment: Whats an example common shell they could be talking about? how would you "scan" for this?

Comment: There's a collection of webshells at [github](https://github.com/tennc/webshell), and I would assume the poster scanned by testing commonly used URL paths to see if anything showed up.